# UIAlert Action xcode 8

Tags: url, swift3, xcode8, uialertview

I'm trying to make a UIAlertaction which can take my game users to my website to see there high scores and others highscores.  could't find a tutorial to show me how to code for a URL. So instead of an alert action to dismiss the alert, the action can be used to take my users to a website. I used a tutorial to get as to come this far. I am new to xcode8 and I am learning. Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am doing my best. Thanks for all the help in advance. Any help would be great. Source Code would be tremendous. I am also using xcode 8. Thanks so much

```
func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let gameset = notification.gameset!
    print(gameset)
}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: do you want to open an external website in safari? Or a webview?

Comment: @dirtydanee Yes, external website in safari. Thank you for replying

Comment: posted my answer.

Comment: @dirtydanee THANK YOU so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do, is to declare the URL you would like to open, and feed that bad boy to the right API.

```
func createAlert (title: String, message:String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: output.text, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
      // Declare a URL what you would like to open
      let url = URL(string: "http://test.io")!
      // Open website in Safari Mobile
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert,animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```